# Visual Studio Code / Git - move changes from master to new branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

After being struggled for some time, I'm posting it here.

I'm working on a project, using `VS Code` as the ide and `git` for version management.

At this point, I have a single branch (`master`) with several commits, and current changes to 3 files (none of these changes are staged so far, and the git tab icon shows the count of changes as 3).

[image]

**Now I want to move these 3 changes to a new branch and have the `master` branch "clear".**

According to answers on SO and other links, I've tried the following:

1. Stashed all changes (at this point the changes do not show on git tab anymore)
   [image]
2. Created a new branch (`contact`) and checked out to it
3. Applied stash changes

Now if I select either the `master` or `contact` branches, the changes to the 3 files are shown:
[image]
[image]

What I expect is to have no changes on `master` and have these 3 changes on `contact` branch only.

Am I doing something wrong? How may I achieve that?

Comment: Investigate using the command line. No need to stach the changed files. Just create a new branch, checkout the branch , the changed files will move with you to the new brach, Stage the new files (git add) and commit the new files.

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for your comment. I've tried creating a new branch but still the changes show on both master and the new branch (what I'm expecting is to not see any changes while on master).

Comment: As soon as you checkout a branch you also move the changed files to the new branch. Just check them in when the branch you want them in is the current branch. A **branch** is just a label of a commit

Comment: Not sure if I got your point. What I would like is to have these 3 changes "segregated" on the new branch (so that I may do additional changes, stage, commit, and so on) and have my `master` clear (so that I may change, stage and commit other files, while having the changes to the 3 files waiting on the new branch).

Comment: read my previous comment until you understand it. Do this in an experiment in a dummy repository and you will get why I mean. git is not CVS or similar VCS-systems.

Comment: After some more research I got the point: changes are not related to any branch until commit. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6551707/6481438) helped clarify it: "You current working directory is always current branch + uncommitted changes (unless you reset them)."